# Automate Machine Learning process with R on multiple datasets

Tags: r, correlation, multiple-databases

I have multiple datasets with different lengths. I want to apply a correlation function to delete correlated variables with 98%. How can I use a loop to apply a correlation function on multiple datasets in the same time and store the variables selected in new dataframes?

How can I also use lasso regression on multiple datasets, also using loop functions? Thank you

```
    H<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))   
    C<-data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=FALSE)))
    R<-data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:30,10,rep=TRUE)))
    E<-data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:40,10,rep=FALSE)))

# Corrélation
    library("caret")
    library("dplyr")
    data.cor <- cor(subset(H, select = -c(X10)))
    high.cor <- findCorrelation(data.cor, cutoff=0.98)
    remove <- names(H[high.cor]) 
    remove <- c(remove)

    myvars <- names(H) %in% remove
    var_selected <- H[!myvars]
    new_data_H <- var_selected
```

Comment: Put the data frames into a list, then loop the list elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way (of several) to do this:

```
# Corrélation
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(99)

H <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))   
C <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=FALSE)))
R <- data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:30,10,rep=TRUE)))
E <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:40,10,rep=FALSE)))

# Combine input datasets a list
inputs <- list(H, C, R, E)
# Empty list to hold results
outputs <- list()

# Loop over each dataset, one at a time
for(df in inputs){
  data.cor <- cor(df)
  high.cor <- findCorrelation(data.cor, cutoff=0.40)
  # Subset the dataset based on `high.cor`
  # Add the subsetted dataset to a output list of datasets
  outputs <- append(outputs, list(df[,-high.cor]))
}

# This is the first dataset processed by the loop
outputs[[1]]
# Second...
outputs[[2]]
# Third...
outputs[[3]]
```

edit: integrating your lasso routine

```
library(glmnet)
library(caret)

set.seed(99)

## Define data (indpendent variables)
H <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))   
C <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=FALSE)))
R <- data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:30,10,rep=TRUE)))
E <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:40,10,rep=FALSE)))
inputs <- list(H, C, R, E)

## Define targets (dependent variables)
Y_H <- data.frame(label_1 = replicate(1,sample(20:35, 10, rep = TRUE)))
Y_C <- data.frame(label_2 = replicate(1,sample(15:65, 10, rep = TRUE)))
Y_R <- data.frame(label_3 = replicate(1,sample(25:45, 10, rep = TRUE)))
Y_E <- data.frame(label_4 = replicate(1,sample(21:80, 10, rep = TRUE)))
targets <- list(Y_H, Y_C, Y_R, Y_E)

## Remove coorelated independent variables
outputs <- list()

for(df in inputs){
  data.cor <- cor(df)
  high.cor <- findCorrelation(data.cor, cutoff=0.40)
  outputs <- append(outputs, list(df[,-high.cor]))
}

## Do lasso regression
lasso_cv <- list()
lasso_model <- list()

for(i in 1:length(outputs)){
  for(j in 1:length(targets)){
    
    lasso_cv[[i]] <- cv.glmnet(
      as.matrix(outputs[[i]]), as.matrix(targets[[j]]), standardize = TRUE, type.measure = "mse",  alpha = 1, nfolds = 3)
    
    lasso_model[[i]] <- glmnet(
      as.matrix(outputs[[i]]), as.matrix(targets[[j]]), lambda = lasso_cv[[i]]$lambda_cv, standardize = TRUE, alpha = 1)
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Skaqqs this is great, can you please help how to apply lasso regression on this lists?

Comment: You're welcome! Sure - how about we start by you showing me how you would do lasso regression on one dataset (you can make an edit to your question if you like), then I can show you how to wrap that in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help, here my problem, i want to permform lasso regression on multiple lists (denpents and independts variables) are stored in two distinct list, list[[1]] corespnds to target[[1]].... How can i apply for loop on two lists, make predictions and store them in variable using the same loop, ( you will find in the bottom of the page what i tried to do). thanks.

Comment: Hi @Abdel_Merhom, I updated my answer to show how you could use loops and lists to do your routine on multiple datasets/targets. Note that I don't have any experience with lasso models, so there is no warranty regarding the details of your statistical approach.

Comment: Great -- you're welcome. If you are satisfied with my answer, I'd suggest accepting it as correct so your question is closed and other readers can more easily find it. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

- Create target variables for each dataframe
- Combhine all dataframes in list
- Combine all targets in list
- Note: every target variable correspond to a dataframe
- Correlation: delete correlated variables
- Performing lasso regression for all lists

Create dataframes

```
set.seed(99)

H <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:20,10,rep=TRUE)))   
C <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=FALSE)))
R <- data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:30,10,rep=TRUE)))
E <- data.frame(replicate(4,sample(0:40,10,rep=FALSE)))

Y_H <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(20:35, 10, rep = TRUE)))
Y_H
names(Y_H)<-
names(Y_H)names(Y_H)=="replicate.1..sample.20.35..10..rep...TRUE.."] <-"label_1"

Y_C <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(15:65, 10, rep = TRUE)))

names(Y_C) <-
names(Y_C)[names(Y_C)=="replicate.1..sample.15.65..10..rep...TRUE.."] <-"label_2" 

 Y_R <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(25:45, 10, rep = TRUE)))
 names(Y_R) <-names(Y_R)[names(Y_R) == "replicate.1..sample.25.45..10..rep...TRUE.."] <- "label_3"


 Y_E <- data.frame(replicate(1,sample(21:80, 10, rep = TRUE)))
 names(Y_E) <-names(Y_E)[names(Y_E) == "replicate.1..sample.15.65..10..rep...TRUE.."] <- "label_4"


 inputs <- list(H, C, R, E)

 targets <- list(Y_H, Y_C, Y_R, Y_E)


 outputs <- list()


 for(df in inputs){
     data.cor <- cor(df)
     high.cor <- findCorrelation(data.cor, cutoff=0.40)
     outputs <- append(outputs, list(df[,-high.cor]))
  }

  library("glmnet")

  lasso_cv <- list()
  lasso_model <- list()

  for(i in outputs){
     for(j in targets){
        lasso_cv[i] <- cv.glmnet(as.matrix(outputs[[i]]), as.matrix(targets[[j]]), 
standardize = TRUE, type.measure="mse",  alpha = 1,nfolds = 3)

         lasso_model[i] <- glmnet(as.matrix(outputs[[i]]), as.matrix(targets[[j]]),lambda = lasso_cv[i]$lambda_cv, alpha = 1, standardize = TRUE)
```

}
}